# Computing $\log\Bigg(\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(-1)^n\frac{\Gamma(n + b)}{\Gamma(n + 1)}\frac{(2n + b)}{\sqrt{2\pi x^3}}e^{-\frac{(2n + b)^2}{8x}}\Bigg)$

Tags: probability-distributions, sequences-and-series

I have been trying to think of ways to evaluate the following expression and hope that I will find some guidance here.

$$\log\Bigg(\frac{2^{b-1}}{\Gamma(b)}\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(-1)^n\frac{\Gamma(n + b)}{\Gamma(n + 1)}\frac{(2n + b)}{\sqrt{2\pi x^3}}e^{-\frac{(2n + b)^2}{8x}}\Bigg)$$

where $b, x \in \mathbb{R}^{+}$.

The most obvious way I tried calculating this is by taking logs of the terms in the summation using a partial sum of around 100 terms. Then apply the `logsumexp` trick to avoid overflow when taking the exponential of the logarithm terms. This worked fine until I realized this method is very unstable when $b>>50$. At such values, the expression starts to overflow or return the wrong values. As shown below:
[image]

I am not strong mathematically so I am sure I am missing some trick or key theorems that could help evaluate this expression reliably at larger values of $b$. I tried using the pochhammer symbol to evaluate the ratio of gammas as $(n + 1)_{(b - 1)}$ but that did not help. I am also aware that
$$ \frac{2^{b-1}}{\Gamma(b)\sqrt{\pi}} = \dfrac{1}{\Gamma(\frac{b}{2})\Gamma(\frac{b + 1}{2})}$$
and
$$ \frac{\Gamma(n + b)}{\Gamma(b)\Gamma(n + 1)} = \frac{1}{nB(n, b)} $$
where $B(x, y)$ is the Beta function; but I don't know how that could be helpful.

EDIT: It is worth noting that the expression can also be re-written as

$$\log\Bigg(\frac{2^{b}}{\Gamma(b)}\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(-1)^n\frac{\Gamma(n + b)}{\Gamma(n + 1)}f\Big(x| 0.5, (2n + b)^2 / 8)\Big)\Bigg)$$
where $f$ is the density function of an Inverse-Gamma distribution with shape parameter $0.5$ and scale $\frac{(2n + h)^2}{8}$.

EDIT2: It is also worth noting that the absolute value of the coefficients of the series increase and then decrease rapidly after a point. This point seems to depends on $b$ and $x$.

EDIT3: Page 10 of this text contains similar expressions but I don't know how to take advantage of them in this particular case: https://empslocal.ex.ac.uk/people/staff/mrwatkin//zeta/biane-pitman-yor.pdf

I have ran out of ideas so that is why I have come here hoping that someone can help guide me to the right way of computing this expression. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is the motivation for such a convoluted expression?

Comment: @SylvainJULIEN It is to compute the log-density of a  distribution. This is the only known expression for it, as far as I am aware from literature

Comment: So it seems likely that this expression has no simpler form.

Comment: @GeraldEdgar I just updated the original post to note a different form for the expression using an inverse-gamma distribution density. I don't think its particularly simpler though,

Comment: Can you do the simplest special case $b=1,x=1$? $$\log\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\sum_{n=1}^\infty (-1)^n (2n+1)e^{-(2n+1)^2/8}\right)$$

Comment: Thanks for your comment @GeraldEdgar. That works but often times I will need the expression for large values of b and x. Evaluating the expression using a partial sum of 200 terms works until $b$  and $x$ are big (e.g. b=100, x=30) then it completely fails due to numerical instability. I was hoping that maybe someone could point out a mathematical result that could significantly simplify evaluation so it won't suffer from instability.

Comment: Is your question in fact what is an asymptotic approximation of this expression for $b$ and $x$ large?

Comment: @username yes, that is the "failsafe" question. Ideally, A way to calculate this expression reliably for all b and x would be the great. But an asymptotic approximation for large b and x would be appreciated too since it is the main reason why I posted this.

Comment: Have you tried saddlepoint approximation of the sum when $b$ and $x$ are large? The result may depend on the relative scaling of $b$ and $x$.

Comment: It seems that $\,b\,$ and $\,x\,$ are assumed to be positive real numbers. If that is correct, please mention that explicitly in your question for the sake of clarity.

Comment: @Somos Yes, you are correct. Thanks for mentioning that, I did not think to include that information. I Just updated the original post.

Comment: I added a density plot that demonstrates the failure when x and b are large.

Answer (score 3):

Denoting your function by $\log f(x)$, it follows from the Biane-Pitman-Yor paper that $$ \int_0^\infty \mathrm{d}x\,e^{-\lambda x} f(x) = \left(\cosh\sqrt{\tfrac{\lambda}{2}}\right)^{-b}.$$
So for integer $b\geq 1$, $f(x)$ is the density of a sum of $b$ i.i.d. random variables with Laplace transform $\left(\cosh\sqrt{\tfrac{\lambda}{2}}\right)^{-1}$. These variables have mean $1/4$ and finite variance $1/24$, so a (local) central limit theorem then gives
$$ f(x) = \sqrt{\frac{12}{\pi b}} e^{-\frac{3}{4b}(b-4x)^2} + o(b^{-1/2})$$
with error uniform in $x$.

Comment: Thanks a lot @TimothyBudd. This approximation is actually identical to the normal approximation of matching moments of variable $X$ and approximating the density of $f(x)$ with a normal distribution with $\mu = 0.25 b$ and  $\sigma^2 = 0.041666688  b$. I had tried this before and was not quite satisfied with the accuracy of the density at the point where the instability occurs. See the plot  [here](https://i.imgur.com/yQtqgh2.png). I am wondering if it there is any way to make the modes match so the approximation is a bit more accurate.

Comment: With a bit more work you can certainly compute some corrections in inverse-powers of $b$ to the central limit theorem. Essentially, you want to make an asymptotic expansion of $(\cosh\sqrt{\lambda/2})^{-b}$ with $\lambda = \mu / b$ as $b\to\infty$ and $\mu$ fixed.